# How can I create an auto increment field on meteor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I need an auto increment field, but not for the primary id, it's only to provide an easy to remember case number to the users of a customers support application.

I found this article that explain how to create an auto increment field on mongodb http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ but this solutions are not supported on minimongo yet.

How can I implement this feature? I don't care if the solutions skip some consecutive case numbers due to errors, but the case number must be unique.

Is there another approach to generate unique and short case numbers? I don't want to give to the users a case code like this PxyooJWSKc3sMz6Lc, because they must refer to their issues with the case number.

**Edit:**

Minimong doesn't support findAndModify, so I can't use the first solution listed on the link I posted. The second solution also require methods not available on minimongo.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the safest solution.  (Minimongo looks like it's not being updated anymore? You might want consider using 10gen's official driver for Python, PyMongo: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/).

Comment: I edited my ask. I think that with the safest solution you refer to the link I posted, but it will not work with minimongo, so I don't have a solution yet. Meteor is a node.js framework, I'm not working with python.

Comment: Sorry, minimongo was/is a python library that came up first. :) So, I'd thought you were talking Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the [mongo-counter package](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-mongo-counter), is posible to create an incrementer with the method `incrementCounter(name)`. The implementation is based on [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#a-counters-collection) accessing directly the database without going through a Meteor Collection.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'addRecord':function(doc) {
        doc.id = incrementCounter('docId');
        MyCollection.insert(doc);
        return doc.id;
    }
});
```

**Update**

There are [new mongo counter packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=mongo-counter) on Atmosphere, probably better than my initial recommendation.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Which package should be installed? There are currently three available on  atmospherejs.com with no clear differentiation between them: konecty:mongo-counter (most popular), mrt:mongo-counter (from awwx), and gabrielengel:konecty-mongo-counter.

Comment: @10basetom, https://atmospherejs.com/?q=mongo-counter. I'm using osv:mongo-counter just now, but I recommend you to check all packages (documentation, usage statistics, support, etc) and select the more convenient for your need.

Answer (score 4):

Well there are a couple of ways you can do this. If you need it to be absolutely consistent you could store the current integer in your collection & use a Meteor.call to add a new record as opposed to doing it from the client.

E.g

**Server side js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'addRecord':function(doc) {
        currentId = MyCollection.findOne({},{sort:{id:-1}}).id || 1;
        doc.id = currentId + 1;
        MyCollection.insert(doc);
        return doc.id;
    }
});
```

**Client side js**

```
doc = {name:"Bob"}
//MyCollection.insert(doc)

//Use this instead
Meteor.call("addRecord", doc, function(err,result) {
    if(result) {
        console.log("Successfully added new record with auto_inc id " + result);
    }
}
```

Doing it with the Meteor.call you would lose one thing though: latency compensation.

### Other possibility

You could store something that is built from a Unix timestamp and shorten it to something more applicable (e.g by cutting off the first few digits):

```
new Date().getTime().toString().substr(4)
```

Comment: I can live without latency compensation in this case but with your first solution I think that the id could be repeated, because the operation is not atomic. I can use this solution for now, because I have very few users, but for another application that I will build I need another solution. Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can understand where it will be non atomic? Mongodb isn't really acid compliant. With node only one thread would run at a go so it should work the same as a MyCollection.insert if not better because an actual true/false callback is returned at the cost of latency compensation

Comment: Mongodb documentation say "The findAndModify() method atomically modifies and returns a single document." It's used on the first solution on the link I posted, so it's guaranteed that when I get an id, it's unique. With your solution, I think that two concurrent requests could get the same id before the insert. I'm not a mongodb or node.js expert, so I'm not sure if what I say is true.

Comment: If node only run a thread, I think you're right and the uniqueness will be guaranteed.

Comment: OK i think this needs a bit more explanation even for me I'm not absolutely certain if its single threaded. I've read a lot of material that says it is at some level and isn't on another. Its evented so each request would be spawned off into a node worker from the main thread, which is single threaded so their uniqueness should still be guaranteed

Comment: This will be atomic only if you're running on only one node server (which is true today, but won't be true in the future if you deploy to *.meteor.com).  The reason why it's atomic in a single node process actually has nothing to do with MongoDB; when you use MyCollection you are accessing the in-memory representation (which is then replicated into the database).  Thus in terms of being atomic this code is no different than using a global variable that you increment (which is also saved to the database).

Comment: If you're happy with running on one node server you might as well use $inc on one document, there's no need to create a new document for each id.

Comment: Another problem with the first approach is that when collection is empty, you will get `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. This happens if you are seeding the database in development.