# Meteor: Could a race condition happen with Meteor.collections on server side?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, race-condition

in my server/server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    saveOnServer: function() {
        var totalCount = Collections.find({
            "some": "condition"
        }).count();
        if (totalCount) {
            var customerId = Collections.update('someId', {
                "$addToSet": {
                    objects: object
                }
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {}
    }
});
```

I'm afraid that when saveOnServer() is called by 2 clients at the same time, it will return the same totalCount for each client and basically end up inserting same integer number into object id. The end goal is to insert row on the server side with an atomic operation that only completes when the `totalCount` is successfully returned and the document is inserted ensuring that no duplicate id exists? I'm trying to not use the mongodb _id but have my own integer incrementing id column.

I'm wondering how I can ensure that a field gets auto-incremented for each insert operation? I am currently relying on getting the total count of documents. Is a race condition possible here? If so, what is the meteor way of dealing with this?

Comment: in principle, the meteor code is too far away from the data to guarantee this. it's a better idea to use dbms tools for such a validation.

Comment: on the server side everything is synchronous right to avoid callback hell using node-fibers? But meteor.collection manages mongodb, is there a way to gurantee a meteor.collection object will be atomic or race condition free?

Comment: Same question is here and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886833/how-can-i-create-an-auto-increment-field-on-meteor.  Your code is not a problem unless you are running on more than one server.

Comment: New meteor package to handle similar problem. https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/autoincrement-counter.  It recommends against such a field as the _id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Meteor's concurrency model, you can imagine a whole method as an uninterruptible block of stuff that happens. In order for Meteor to switch from running one method midway to say, starting another method, you need to "yield"—the method needs to signal, "I can be interrupted."

Methods yield whenever they do something asynchronous, which in practice means any time you do a database update or call a method with a callback in Meteor 0.6.5 and later. Since you give your `update` call a callback, Meteor will **always** try to do something in between the call to `update` and the `update`'s callback. However, in Meteor 0.6.4.2 and earlier, database updates were uninterruptible regardless of the use of callbacks.

However, multiple calls to `saveOnServer` will happen in order and do not cause a race condition. You can call `this.unblock()` to allow multiple calls to `saveOnServer` to occur "simultaneously"—i.e., not share the same queue, labeled `saveOnServer queue`, of uninterruptible blocks of stuff.

Given the code you have, another method modifying `Collections` can change the value of `count()` between the call and the update.

You can prevent one method from making the other invalid midway by implementing the following data models:

```
saveOnServer : function () {
// ...
  Collections.update({_id:someId, initialized:true, collectionCount: {$gt: 0}},
    {$addToSet: {objects: object}});
///...
}
```

When adding objects to `Collections`:

```
insertObject: function() {
//...
  var count = Collections.find({some: condition}).count();
  Collections.insert({_id:someId, initialized:false, collectionCount: count});
  Collections.update({initialized:false},
    {$set:{initialized:true}, $inc: {collectionCount: 1}});
}
```

Note, while this may seem inefficient, it reflects the exact cost of making an update and insert in different methods behave the way you intend. In `saveOnServer` you cannot insert.

Conversely, if you removed the callback from `Collections.update`, it will occur synchronously and there will be no race conditioning Meteor 0.6.5 and later.

Comment: It will only happen in order if you are using only 1 server. If you 2+ servers I think you will have race conditions on mongodb writes.

Comment: Check my note to clarify as I understand the Meteor code better.

Comment: New note added. My comments about giving callbacks to `update` were inaccurate until 0.6.5

Comment: Even "synchronous" database operations yield to other fibers. The event loop is not blocked during this time - regardless of whether you provide a callback or not.

Comment: @AndrewMao So, how do you ensure method calls are queued and processed in order then? See also this new question about a similar problem I'm having right now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987510/concurrency-between-meteor-settimeout-and-meteor-methods?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can make this collection have a unique key on an index field, and then keep it updated as follows:

1) Whenever you insert into the collection, first do a query to get the maximum index and insert the document with index + 1.

2) To find out the number of documents just do the query to get the max of the index.

Insertion is now a pair of queries, a read and a write, so it can fail. (DB ops can always fail, though.) However, it can *never* leave the database in an inconsistent state - the Mongo index will guarantee that.

The syntax for building an index in Meteor is this:

```
MyCollection._ensureIndex('index', {unique: 1});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is from a mechanism hibernate/jpa follows - and that is to set up a collision field.  Most of the time, this can be an update timestamp that is set on each update.  Just prior to doing any update, query the update timestamp.  Then you can specify the update where the update timestamp is what you just fetched.  If it has changed in the interim, the update won't happen - and you check the return code/count that the row was updated or not.
JPA does this automatically for you when you add an annotation for this collision field - but this is essentially what it does in behind the scenes