# Concurrency between Meteor.setTimeout and Meteor.methods

Tags: node.js, multithreading, mongodb, meteor, concurrency

In my Meteor application to implement a turnbased multiplayer game server, the clients receive the game state via publish/subscribe, and can call a Meteor method `sendTurn` to send turn data to the server (they cannot update the game state collection directly).

```
var endRound = function(gameRound) {
    // check if gameRound has already ended / 
    // if round results have already been determined
    //     --> yes: 
                  do nothing
    //     --> no:
    //            determine round results
    //            update collection
    //            create next gameRound
};

Meteor.methods({
    sendTurn: function(turnParams) {
        // find gameRound data 
        // validate turnParams against gameRound
        // store turn (update "gameRound" collection object) 
        // have all clients sent in turns for this round?
        //      yes --> call "endRound"
        //      no  --> wait for other clients to send turns
    }
});
```

To implement a time limit, I want to wait for a certain time period (to give clients time to call `sendTurn`), and then determine the round result - but only if the round result has not already been determined in `sendTurn`.

**How should I implement this time limit on the server?**

My naive approach to implement this would be to call  `Meteor.setTimeout(endRound, <roundTimeLimit>)`.

Questions:

- What about concurrency? I assume I should update collections synchronously (without callbacks) in `sendTurn` and `endRound` (?), but would this be enough to eliminate race conditions? (Reading the 4th comment on the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007014/meteor-could-a-race-condition-happen-with-meteor-collections-on-server-side) about synchronous database operations also yielding, I doubt that)
- In that regard, what does "per request" mean in the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) in my context (the function `endRound` called by a client method call and/or in server `setTimeout`)?

  > In Meteor, your server code runs in a single thread per request, not in the asynchronous callback style typical of Node.
- In a multi-server / clustered environment, (how) would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, and it's trickier than it looks. First off I'd like to point out that I've implemented a solution to this exact problem in the following repos:

> https://github.com/ldworkin/meteor-prisoners-dilemma
>   https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor

To summarize, the problem basically has the following properties:

- Each client sends in some action on each round (you call this `sendTurn`)
- When all clients have sent in their actions, run `endRound`
- Each round has a timer that, if it expires, automatically runs `endRound` anyway
- `endRound` must execute exactly once per round regardless of what clients do

Now, consider the properties of Meteor that we have to deal with:

- Each client can have exactly one outstanding method to the server at a time (unless `this.unblock()` is called inside a method). Following methods wait for the first.
- All timeout and database operations on the server can yield to other fibers

This means that whenever a method call goes through a yielding operation, values in Node or the database can change. This can lead to the following potential race conditions (these are just the ones I've fixed, but there may be others):

- In a 2-player game, for example, two clients call `sendTurn` at exactly same time. Both call a yielding operation to store the turn data. Both methods then check whether 2 players have sent in their turns, finding the affirmative, and then `endRound` gets run twice.
- A player calls `sendTurn` right as the round times out. In that case, `endRound` is called by both the timeout and the player's method, resulting running twice again.
- Incorrect fixes to the above problems can result in starvation where `endRound` never gets called.

You can approach this problem in several ways, either synchronizing in Node or in the database.

- Since only one Fiber can actually change values in Node at a time, if you don't call a yielding operation you are guaranteed to avoid possible race conditions. So you can cache things like the turn states in memory instead of in the database. However, this requires that the caching is done correctly and doesn't carry over to clustered environments.
- Move the `endRound` code outside of the method call itself, using something else to trigger it. This is the approach I've taken which ensures that only the timer or the final player triggers the end of the round, not both (see [here](https://github.com/ldworkin/meteor-prisoners-dilemma/blob/master/server/server.js#L121) for an implementation using `observeChanges`).
- In a clustered environment you will have to synchronize using only the database, probably with conditional update operations and atomic operators. Something like the following:

  ```
  var currentVal;

  while(true) {
    currentVal = Foo.findOne(id).val; // yields

    if( Foo.update({_id: id, val: currentVal}, {$inc: {val: 1}}) > 0 ) {
      // Operation went as expected
      // (your code here, e.g. endRound)
      break;
    }
    else {
      // Race condition detected, try again
    }
  }
  ```

The above approach is primitive and probably results in bad database performance under high loads; it also doesn't handle timers, but I'm sure with some thinking you can figure out how to extend it to work better.

You may also want to see this [timers code](https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor/blob/master/lib/timers_server.js) for some other ideas. I'm going to extend it to the full setting that you described once I have some time.

Comment: I found this "Update Document if Current" pattern you described in the mongo docs https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/update-if-current/

Just a heads up - "Changed in version 2.6: The db.collection.update() method now returns a WriteResult() object that contains the status of the operation. Previous versions required an extra db.getLastErrorObj() method call."

Comment: @thomers does that actually affect the Meteor API or is it abstracted away?

Comment: This is a great strategy for implementing a lock-like device in meteor! In fact, I already had a "length" parameter lying around - so I just used that, and it works amazingly. I just have one question though: is there any way to get the *actual* value of the `findOne()` inside the critical section? Most of the time it's the same, but when there actually was a race, the other thread's updates are not visible anymore! Can I call `findOne()` again in the critical section (and potentially yield) or will this just cause a deadlock?

Comment: Okay. I did it anyway because I am heinously under qualified to own a computer and it is doing the thing where it looks like it your concurrent app works. Lol. But here is my take on the situation anyway: there isn't actually a cyclical dependency because even though both inner `findOne()`s (may) yield, they don't really wait on each other, just IO via the event loop and a wrapped asynchronous call. Hopefully haha.