# wait for async or promise to return

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, promise, async-await

Yes I already read some of the answers here but I somehow could not solve my problem which is the following:

I need to wait for the result of an async call.

```
function clientSideFunction(){ // cannot be async
  const waitForResult = callServer(); // no await here because clientSidefunction cannot be async
  return waitForResult; // must be called after callServer 
}

async function callServer() { // need to get rid of async keyword
  const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => Meteor.call('someServerSideFunction',            (error, result) => {
    if (error) return reject(error);
    resolve(result);
  }));
  return result;
}
```

I hope it's clear what I try to achieve.

Basically, I want to wait for the result to be ready before I continue the code execution after calling the `callServer` function.

It must not be async-await if there are other ways (promises).

Comment: Did you try using `then` and callbacks?

Comment: And why do you want to get rid of the async keyword?

Comment: "Basically i want to wait for the result to be ready, before i continue the code execution after calling the callServer function" — You can't. That is what async means!

Comment: "*clientSidefunction cannot be async*" - why not? And if it really can't, then that means that you cannot call async functions such as `callServer` from it.

Comment: @k0pernikus i cannot return `waitforResult` inside `.then` function?

Comment: The return value of a function passed to `then` is adopted as the resolution of the promise. Outside of the promise chain, you still have the promise and not the value.

Comment: @k0pernikus, Bergi: because i can't make the outer function async

Comment: You can't have the resolved value of a promise before the promise resolves. This is a constraint imposed by living in a universe with linear time.

Comment: clientSidefunction should be async. how can you get result  from sync method if you are calling async method internally . you will not get result if you use sync method.  because you are calling async method inside sync.

Comment: @Quentin that's why i want to wait until it resolves....

Comment: @Gobliins — You can't. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Quentin Then how can you control race conditions?

Comment: https://forums.meteor.com/t/race-conditions-on-multiple-instances-of-meteor-accessing-mongodb/37795/2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007014/meteor-could-a-race-condition-happen-with-meteor-collections-on-server-side