# Generate account number incrementing by 1

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I haven't been able to find a clear answer for this.
How can I generate an account number for a new user when the account is created. I want the number to be 8 digits long and start at 00000001 going up by one number for each user.

I assume what I need to do is query the db for the highest value and then +1 but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an auto increment field on meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886833/how-can-i-create-an-auto-increment-field-on-meteor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you don't have any holes then you can more simply do:

```
var nextNumber = Meteor.Users.count() + 1;
```

But if there might be gaps:

```
var nextNumber = Meteor.Users.findOne({},{ sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 1 })._id + 1;
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you're going to do this you'll want the id to be a number and not a string. You can pad with zeros on output.